# Install4j Web url for installer images

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to configure Install4j in such a way that I can specify a web url for the installer icons and images? I know we can update a image but i have case where the images need to be fetched from a web server. Thanks

Edit: I want the left image (blue) on the left to be downloaded from a web URL.

[installer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDQRE.png)

Comment: Hello, can you please elaborate your question or any existing links which you have already tried.

Comment: I updated the question. I couldn't find anything as of now. So not even sure if this is possible or not. thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 8 this is not supported. I've created an issue for this feature request.